# Using snprintf to concatenate giving segmentation fault in c

Tags: c

I am trying to compare szFileName1 and szFileName2 , if they are not same, then I am renaming it, but when I am trying to concatenate using snprintf it's giving segmentation fault.what mistake am I doing here?

```
typedef struct{
  char filePath[100];
} filectx;

void filename1(filectx *ctx, const char ** szFileName1){
    *szFileName1 = ctx->filepath;
}


void filename2(const char ** szFileName2){
    char buf[20] = "/usr/bin/abb.txt";
    snprintf(szFileName2, sizeof(szFileName2), "%s%s", szFileName2, buf);
}

int main(){

   const char* szFileName1 = NULL;
   const char *szFileName2 = malloc(100);
   filectx ctx;
   ctx.filePath = "/usr/bin/abc.txt";
   filename1(&ctx, &szFileName1);
   filename2(&szFileName2);

   if(strcmp(szFileName1, szFileName2) != 0){
       const char szFilePath1[200] = "/local/"; 
       const char szFilePath2[200] = "/local/";
       snprintf(szFilePath1, sizeof(szFilePath1), "%s%s", szFilePath1, szFileName1);
       snprintf(szFilePath2, sizeof(szFilePath2), "%s%s", szFilePath2, szFileName2);
       int ret = rename(szFilePath1, szFilePath2);
   }

   free(szFileName2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Segmentation fault" = Time to open this code in your debugger and see what happens just prior to failure. Have you stepped through it yet? These buffers look really tiny and in one case completely unnecessary. Use `char buf* = "..."` instead of some arbitrary 20-character buffer with fixed contents. When manipulating paths be sure you can accommodate `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: I see too many problems in your code.

Comment: `szFilePath1` is declared `const`, so you can't use it as the destination of `snprintf()`.

Comment: You can't use the same variable as the source and destination in `snprintf()`.

Comment: If you want to append to a string, use `strncat()`.

Comment: The consecutive lines `filectx ctx;` and
   `ctx.filePath = "/usr/bin/abc.txt";` should not compile; you should be using `strcpy()` to copy a string, or initializing the variable with `filectx ctx = { "/usr/bin/abc.txt" };`.  There are a myriad other problems too.

Comment: The 1 major problem is that code is compiled without all warnings enable - or is a weak compiler.  pavikirthi, save time.  Enable all warning - faster feedback than posting on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
const char szFilePath1[200] = "/local/"; 
const char szFilePath2[200] = "/local/";
```

as well as others as your function arguments, you declare those variables `const`. You then try to write to them with `snprintf`. Don't make these `const`.

You also can't reuse a variable as source and destination in `snprintf`.

I'm surprised that the compiler allowed you to compile this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is with the arguments you pass to snprintf(). 
snprintf() expects an argument of type string  ("char *"), but not "char **".

Here you are passing a pointer instead of the actual string. So when it tries to access the address it gives segmentation fault.

Change the parameters in the functions filename1() and filename2() to "char *" type and see. It should work.

Hope this helps.

Kranthi

Comment: Yes `const char ** szFileName2 ... snprintf(szFileName2, sizeof(szFileName2), "%s%s", szFileName2, buf);` is bad - wrong number of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Although snprintf() doesn't work in your case, why don't you use strcat() or strncat()?
Instead of

> snprintf(szFilePath1, sizeof(szFilePath1), "%s%s", szFilePath1, szFileName1);

you can write

```
strncat(szFilePath1, szFileName1, strlen(szFilePath1));
```

And by the way:
**WHY** did you write

> sizeof(szFilePath1)

?
So, points to improve

1. In the very beginning:

> *szFileName1 = ctx->filepath;

Not a nice thing to do. It's better to use strcpy()/strncpy(). And passing char ** argument also looks pretty strange.

2. Stated above. Usage of snprintf's

Comment: pavikirthi, are you a c programmer? I am asking since your code looks as if you tried to apply concepts from over languages in c.